# How to search multi line string with order in shell script?

Tags: shell

I have a file containing a list of strings, for example:

```
abc
search1
lkj
sdfdgs
search2
kkd
#search3
search3
```

How can I keep all lines matching `search1`, `search2` or `search3`, that is the

`command search1,search2,search3`
for 
expected output is:

```
search1
search2
search3
```

if `command search3,search1,search2`
for 
expected output is:

```
not matching or print nothing
```

Note that the `#search3` line should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `grep` utility:

```
% grep '^\(search1\|search2\|search3\)' file.txt
search1
search2
search3
```